# calling typeid on template difference between GNU C++ and MSVC problem

Tags: c++, typeid

I am trying to port a code that should work and compile on both Linux (GCC/C++) and windows (MSVC)
however the following line is giving me trouble

```
template <class TDerived>
struct Event
{
    inline static std::string eventId = typeid(TDerived).name();
};

struct Derived : public Event<Derived>
{
    Derived() = default;

};
```

The code uses `typeid` and `name()` to set the event name,

In GNU/C++ it compiles properly in both Linux and Apple (Clang), and even in Windows using MingW.
but in windows using MSVC
it gives the following error

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'Derived'
message : see declaration of 'Derived'
message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Event<Derived>' being compiled
```

basically because `Derived` is incomplete at this time and is not visible in the `Event` scope.
But why does GNU/GCC, MingW and Clang succesfuly compiled it? Do we have a workaround in MSVC (Visual Studio)?

Comment: Always specify version numbers, platforms type, etc.

Comment: Seems that MSVC fails in many situation with CRTP (probably depending on the version) see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1110083/msvc-compiler-versions-fail-to-compile-valid-code.html

Answer (score 3):

C++ standard says:

> [expr.typeid]
>
> When typeid is applied to a type-id ... If the type of the type-id is a class type or a reference to a class type, the class **shall be completely-defined.**

As far as I can tell, the class isn't completely-defined in that context. If that interpretation is correct, then the rule is violated and the program is ill-formed. That said, I'm not 100% sure since template instantiation makes the rules quite complex.

> But why does GNU/GCC, MingW and Clang succesfuly compiled it?

For whatever reason, their implementation can apparently cope with non-completely defined classes. They aren't required to successfully compile it. Technically they do not conform to the standard if they do not provide a diagnostic message (assuming the the interpretation of program being ill-formed is correct).

> Do we have a workaround in MSVC (Visual Studio)?

Defining a non-inline static member seems to work in godbolt:

```
template <class TDerived>
struct Event
{
    static std::string eventId;
};

template <class TDerived>
std::string Event<TDerived>::eventId = typeid(TDerived).name();
```

---

Note that the name is implementation defined and is not going to be the same across all language implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around and it works.

```
template <class TDerived>
struct Event
{
private:
    static std::string getEventId() { return typeid(TDerived).name(); }

public:
    inline static std::string eventId = getEventId();
};
```